# Git pre-commit hook gist

Tags: git, githooks

I found this snippet of code https://gist.github.com/wrboyce/786460

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

COMPRESSOR=$(whence -p yui-compressor)
[ -z $COMPRESSOR ] && exit 0;

function _compress {
        local fname=$1:t
        local dest_path=$1:h
        local min_fname="$dest_path/${fname:r}.min.${fname:e}"
        $COMPRESSOR $1 > $min_fname
        git add $min_fname
}

for file in $(find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.+\.(css|js)$' -and -not -iregex '.+\.min\.(css|js)$'); _compress $file
```

On my osx machine it says:

> .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: whence: command not found

I believe this is for linux only? Could anyone help to do this on a mac? I want to minify my css and javascript before it is sent to the remote production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's for Linux only:

> The whence command is a *Korn Shell feature* that tells how a name
>   would be interpreted by the shell: it detects commands and aliases,
>   and searches your path.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

COMPRESSOR=$(which yui-compressor)
[ -z $COMPRESSOR ] && exit 0;

function _compress {
        local fname=$1:t
        local dest_path=$1:h
        local min_fname="$dest_path/${fname:r}.min.${fname:e}"
        $COMPRESSOR $1 > $min_fname
        git add $min_fname
}

for file in $(find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.+\.(css|js)$' -and -not -iregex '.+\.min\.(css|js)$'); _compress $file
```

Comment: Strange, whence is also a zsh builtin. I actually wrote the original  gist on my OSX machine.